# datepicker plugin show on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker from jQuery UI and customizing its CSS according to my needs. I want to made the [datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Q46.png) open on button click which itself shows dateinfo [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Q46.png)

My current html code:

```
<div class="date-pickup-block">
                        <div type="text">
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
```

and my javascript code is:

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Show Date',

        dateFormat: "D dd/mm/yy",           
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: false,
        dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    });

    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    });
});
```

and my current datepicker when i click on the [show Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBA7E.png), it looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op0iP.png)

CSS COde:

```
.ui-datepicker {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 255px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    padding: 15px;

    }

    .ui-datepicker a{
        text-decoration: none;
        }

    .ui-datepicker table{
        width: 100%;        
        }

    .ui-datepicker thead{
        color: #f36846;
        }

    .ui-datepicker-header{
        color: #f36846;
        font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
        font-size: 15px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        }

    .ui-datepicker tbody:before {
        content: "-";
        display: block;
        line-height: 1em;
        color: transparent;
        }

    .ui-datepicker-title{
        text-align: center;
        }

    .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;        
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        line-height: 600%;
        overflow: hidden;
        }

    .ui-datepicker-prev {
        background-image: url('../imgs/pickup-details/calander_left.png');      
        float: left;
        background-position: center 2px;
        }

    .ui-datepicker-next {
        background-image: url('../imgs/pickup-details/calander_right.png');
        float: right;
        background-position: center 2px;
        }

    .ui-datepicker tbody td {

        font: 10px 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';

        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
        }

    .ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
        color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 31px;
        line-height: 31px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 31px;
        }


    .ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
        background: #f36846;
        color: #fff;   
        }
```

I don't know mucj jQuery so customizing is difficult from jQuery. What changes does i need to make in both HTML and jQuery to make it look [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Q46.png)

Comment: They look like completely different date pickers and most likely not an easy change. You should be posting the original CSS code, that would make it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        constrainInput: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Select'
    }); });</script><input id="datepicker" disabled="disabled" />
```

Use this it will work